# xml literal with string.format

Tags: vb.net

How can I use the vb [xml literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384832.aspx) within a `string.format` statement?

I want to achieve this but with vb xml literals

```
Dim test1 As String = 
String.Format(<outer>
    <inner1>{0}</inner1>
    <inner2/>
</outer>,32)
```

Comment: XML literals are used to create `XElement`s. `String.Format` is used to create `String`s. What do you need, an XML string or an XElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what an xml literal is for...

```
    Dim xml = <outer><inner1></inner1><inner2/></outer>
    xml...<inner1>.First.Value = 32
    Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (just needed to add `.ToString()` at the end of your XML).

```
Dim test1 As String = String.Format(<outer>
                                      <inner1>{0}</inner1>
                                      <inner2/>
                                    </outer>.ToString(), 32)
```